# python django regular express confused

Tags: python, django

```
^get/(?P<lowercase_string>[a-z]+)/(?P<integer>\d+)/(?P<date1>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/(?P<date2>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/
```

this is a peace of code from django.

what does `?P<lowercase_string>` mean? is that a Regex? what is a express start with a "?"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/
Get the official explanation, and it is very helpful :

In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular-expression groups is (?Ppattern), where name is the name of the group and pattern is some pattern to match.

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$',views.article_detail),]
```

This accomplishes exactly the same thing as the previous example, with one subtle difference: The captured values are passed to view functions as keyword arguments rather than positional arguments. For example:

A request to /articles/2005/03/ would call the function views.month_archive(request, year='2005', month='03'), instead of views.month_archive(request, '2005', '03').
A request to /articles/2003/03/03/ would call the function views.article_detail(request, year='2003', month='03', day='03').

Comment: Sorry, but read it first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?P<lowercase_string>` part of above regex is just storing the value captured by parenthesis so that it may be used in python code later.

Look at this part of the regex in your example

> `(?P<lowercase_string>[a-z]+)`

removing the confusing part of the regex leaves

> `([a-z]+)`

parenthesis around `[a-z]+` in regex means capture the match made by `[a-z]+` and store it in `$1` variable in regex if you want some other name for the captured data so that you may use in  Python code later then you can use

> `(?P<lowercase_string>[a-z]+)`

as is done here.

Here's an example,

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(?P<number>[A-Za-z]+)")
print regex.search("Hi This is a Test.").group('number')
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: If `regex.search("Hi This is a Test.")` doesn't find the expression within the string, it will return `NoneType` object and thus raise an AttributeError: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. It would be better to split the last line into two separate statements.

Comment: And you have a typo in your answer. Twice you have `[1-z]+` where it should be `[a-z]+`. Otherwise the answer is correct and the explanation is clear.